# Calling a micro service

Tags: java, spring-mvc, dropwizard

I looked for the similar question but could not find any . I have a micro service created with drop-wizard which is running in localhost:9000.

I am working in another project(with spring mvc) running in 8080. I wan to call the above service which gives me string back from any of my controllers in main project .lets say the path is "localhost:9000/giveMeString" .

Comment: To clarify: you want to make an HTTP request to localhost:9000/giveMeString from another application running on port 8080?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Apache's HTTP Client. See this example borrowed from their documentation:

```
  // Create an instance of HttpClient.
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

  // Create a method instance.
  GetMethod method = new GetMethod("http://localhost:9000/giveMeString");

  // Execute the method.
  int statusCode = client.executeMethod(method);

  // Read the response body.
  byte[] responseBody = method.getResponseBody();

  //Print the response
  System.out.println(new String(responseBody));
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're really going down the microservice path, note that creating an HTTP client for every request and making synchronous, blocking requests won't really scale.

Here are a few ideas, if you're using Spring:

### Create a single RestTemplate instance

You can create a [single RestTemplate instance](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html#rest-client-access) and inject it in multiple places in your application.

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {
  @Bean
  public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());
  }
}
```

### Better, wrap that REST client with a Cache

Check out [Sagan's take on this](https://github.com/spring-io/sagan/blob/4cd2312701cbfe4ee750d94df9b9aa8a4b816546/sagan-common/src/main/java/sagan/support/cache/CachedRestClient.java).

### Even better, go asynchronous

You can use an [AsyncRestTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html#rest-async-resttemplate); very useful, especially if your Controllers need to make multiple requests and if you don't want to block your webapp thread. Your Controller can even return a `DeferredResult` or a `ListenableFuture`, which will make your webapp more scalable.

### And Spring Cloud + Netflix

You can also check [Spring Cloud](http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/) and [Spring Cloud Netflix](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/).
You'll see there interesting features: load-balancing, recovery, circuit breakers, etc.